# How to format the time which is shown on notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have problem modifying my alarm application's notification, i want to change the time that shown by notification by using these code :

```
   .......
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, addMinute);
   notification.when = cal.getTimeInMillis();
   notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
```

But the problem is the notification time is not in the right format it show mm/dd/yy, instead of hh:mm , is it possible to change the format? i cant find apropriate method to change them.

i did search but i cant find any way to do that. any suggestion how to format the time in notification?

Thanks

Comment: You can just remove time

Comment: Would you help give me a hint? I've been searching for hour, cant find the way to remove it.. :(

Comment: So you dont want to show time in the notification message is that it?

Comment: everybody s welcome! but what's the solution now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. I couldn't figure out how to delete or format the time on standard notification, but I can create custom notification using [NotificationBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html), and passed formatted string time to the custom notification instead of Time.